# how do I add a background image to a textfield in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe

Hey guys I am developing an app for IPhone and I am trying to figure out how to add a background image to a textfield that is populated by phone numbers a user stores.

My function -

```
function configureLabel():void
{
    label = new TextField();
    label.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
    label.background = true;
    label.border = true;
    label.width = 50;
    label.x = 55;
    label.y = 80;
    //label.htmlText = "whasfd";
    var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
    format.font = "arial";
    format.color = 0xFF0000;
    format.size = 10;
    format.underline = false;
    //format.leftMargin = 50;


    label.defaultTextFormat = format;
    addChild(label);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could make a display object class that contains the textfield and the background. Then you simply add an event listener to the textfield that listens for any changes. Every time there is a change the background would resize itself to the textfield's current size.

Here is an example:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.LoaderInfo;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;
    import flash.text.TextFieldType;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {

        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

        }// end function

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            var loader:Loader = new Loader();
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
            loader.load(new URLRequest("images/koala.jpg"));

        }// end function

        private function onComplete(e:Event):void {

            var bitmap:Bitmap = ((e.target as LoaderInfo).content as Bitmap);

            var container:TextFieldContainer = new TextFieldContainer();
            container.textField.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
            container.textField.defaultTextFormat = new TextFormat(null, null, 0xFF0000);
            container.textField.type = TextFieldType.INPUT;
            container.textField.multiline = true;
            container.setBackground(bitmap);
            addChild(container);

        }// end function

    }// end class

}// end package

import flash.display.DisplayObject;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.text.TextField;

class TextFieldContainer extends Sprite {

    private var _textField:TextField;
    private var _backgroundContainer:Sprite;

    public function get textField():TextField {

        return _textField;

    }// end function

    public function TextFieldContainer():void {

        _backgroundContainer = new Sprite();
        addChild(_backgroundContainer);

        _textField = new TextField();
        _textField.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, onChange);
        addChild(_textField);

    }// end function

    private function onChange(e:Event):void {

        resizeBackground();

    }// end function

    public function setBackground(displayObject:DisplayObject):void {

        if (_backgroundContainer.numChildren > 0) {
            _backgroundContainer.removeChildAt(0);
        }// end if

        _backgroundContainer.addChild(displayObject);

        resizeBackground();

    }// end function

        private function resizeBackground():void {
            _backgroundContainer.width = _textField.width;
            _backgroundContainer.height = _textField.height;
        }

}// end function
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is that you can't - Flash TextFields do not support a background image.

Instead position a Bitmap behind your textfield.

Comment: Hmmm so what I want to do it have a list populated and with like a background image behind each element...no way of doing that?

Comment: Create your custom class from a Sprite, with a Bitmap and a TextField as members, and position the Bitmap behind the TextField, and use that class in place of the TextField.

Answer (score 0):

This can do a trick.

txt.htmlText ="http://www.flexflashforum.com/styles/prosilver/imageset/site_logo.gif' width='139' height='52'> This image is under Dynamic text field of flash "